# How to check if $meta_key in array has a value before running an if-statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, multidimensional-array, metadata

I am working on a some code that will post information from custom field to the database.

The following code checks to see if the **$meta_key** is present:

```
// Apply filters to keys
$this->keys = apply_filters('sc_meta_keys', $this->keys);

// See if the current meta_key is in the array keys
if($this->in_array_recursive($meta_key, $this->keys)) {

if($action == "add") {
//information from array gets added to DB
} 

}else{
//Do something else
}
```

I am however unsure how to check if there is a value in the **meta_key**, as I don't want the if-statement to run if there is no value present.

The array will always have keys however not every post will necessarily have the custom fields filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check if a variable is set and utlize short circuit operators to reduce the processing time of the conditionals.  As You haven't included the logic for where you are setting **$meta_key** I'll check if it's set or not to be sure.

```
$this->keys = apply_filters('sc_meta_keys', $this->keys);

// See if the current meta_key is in the array keys
if( isset( $meta_key ) && ! empty( $this->keys ) && $this->in_array_recursive( $meta_key, $this->keys ) ) {

    if($action == "add") {
        //information from array gets added to DB
    } 

    }
    else {
        //Do something else
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it's still passing the information through. I set up the keys in  the **sc_meta_keys** function as follows `$keys['lat'][] = "latitude";` and `$keys['lng'][] = "longitude";` Is it seeing it as a string albeit an empty one?

Comment: @MrBiggRJD you're setting the array values so it won't be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should do this. This would check if $metakey exists .

```
// See if the current meta_key is in the array keys
if (isset( $meta_key )) && (is_array($meta_key) && ($this->in_array_recursive($meta_key, $this->keys))) {
```